# Break out of an ipython command

Tags: ipython

Simply, how do I break out of this `....:` after I've type a command? And why is Ipython doing this what is wrong with my edot equation?

```
In [12]: edot = (1 - mu) * A * alpha * K**(alpha - 1) * L**beta * n**(1 - (alpha + beta)) * e - 1 / gamma * (A * K**alpha * L**beta * n**-(alpha + beta) * (1 - (1 - mu) * (alpha + beta) - phi)
   ....: 
   ....:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can press Ctrl-C to return to the normal prompt.

IPython shows the ... when you have unmatched parenthesis or brackets.

Viewing quickly your equation I think you need a `)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to accept but I cannot. I would not normally ask such a trivial question, but google failed because the string "....:" is not searchable and I didn't know how to word it.

Comment: @WalrustheCat any more details? what expression are you trying? is it IPython or IPython QTConsole?

Comment: I believe it was in the middle of a string literal, and it's the IPython prompt.  Thanks

Comment: I've just tested it in a GNU/Linux terminal with IPython 2 and in I can't reproduce the error, when I have unmatched quotes, brackets or indented blocks I can always quit with Ctrl-C.

Comment: thanks @Fernando .  I'm on OSX, using Homebrew IPython 3.0.0.  In the midst of a multi-line string or dictionary definition, I'm not able to exit with Ctrl-C.